# Is it possible to activate tensorflow anaconda environment inside a python script

Tags: python, python-3.x, tensorflow, anaconda

What I want to do is to create a GUI for my tensorflow program.
However, I can't seem to run my conda tensorflow environment inside my python script.

I have already tried this code

```
subprocess.call("activate tensorflow", shell=True)
```

but it still says that it cant find the tensorflow module.

Comment: You need to activate the environment **before** running the Python code, for example using a shell script or batch file.

Comment: I really appreciate the reply! Now I'll try to focus on researching and creating the batch file you suggested! Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not in general. A virtualenv has its own copy of the Python interpreter, possibly with a different version than the system-wide (most problematically, one can be Python 2 and the other Python 3). Once you have already started one Python interpreter you cannot hot-swap it with another.

If you know that both versions of the interpreter are the same, then you could try something like adding the virtualenv lib and site-packages directories at the beginning of `sys.path` before doing anything else, but that's not really clean and even then some things may not work correctly (besides, I think the default virtualenv and the Anaconda virtualenv directory structures are somewhat different). Also, even if this worked, it would definitely *not* be possible to dance around from one virtualenv to another after you start importing modules (once you import a module, there is no way to "unimport" it, and every future reference will use the one loaded first, no matter what `sys.path` says).

It would be better to just have a different process to work in the virtualenv. You can run a second interpreter directly from the first one, or call a batch/shell script to do it for you, or replace the first Python script with a batch/shell script, etc.

Comment: Greatly appreciate your fast response!  Just wanna clarify if I understood the things you recommended. So basically, I have to create a batch/shell script that will run or activate my tensorflow envi and then execute my python script. Is that right? Thanks again!

Comment: @narcisskylake Yes, well, the best way may depend on what exactly you are doing, but for example that is what I do to run several experiments overnight (a shell script that activates the environment and then calls the training script once per given "experiment description" file).

Comment: What I really wanna do is to create a simple GUI using PyQt for my image recognition program. As usual, I'm using opencv, and wanted it to be inside a pretty interface rather than being in a separate window. That's all what it is.. Thanks for the help again! :)

Comment: @narcisskylake Ahh I see... Well if you can do everything from within the virtualenv it would be easier I think, if for some reason you want/need to run the main interface from outside the virtualenv you could still call the virtualenv program with `subprocess` or something (like a shell command), although it may get a bit dirty.